# How to upload image from Java client to Node.js

Tags: java, node.js

I am trying to send image from Java client to Node server but nodejs does not get any file. I am using Apache MultipartEntityBuilder in Java.
I have used multer and busBoy neither of them worked
Java Code:

```
String name = String.valueOf((new Date()).getTime());
            String extension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."));
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:3000/gallery/upload");

            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

            builder.addBinaryBody("uploadFile",new File(filePath),
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,name+extension);
            HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
            httpPost.setEntity(multipart);

            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            client.close();
```

Node JS does not see any file

```
multer = require('multer'),
        uploadFile = multer({dest: '../images/public/images/UploadedImages/'});
    router.post('/upload',uploadFile.single('uploadFile'),(req,res) =>{
        console.log(req.body.file);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
```

Comment: Are u getting any error Java client side?

Comment: No there was no error, butr I solved It the file was in req.file not req.body.file